# About AVPlayer's volume at real device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play local audio file and audio stream.

Everything work fine at real device except volume.
The volume is very low. even i set device volume max.
but earphone's volume is normal.
i guess some how speaker's volume is become earphone's volume.

and it's also works fine with Simulator.

I have tried the MPMusicPlayerController , AVMutableAudioMix to set volume.
but nothing works.

I'm totally confused.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the solution from [developer.Apple Technical Q&A QA1716](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1716/_index.html)

AVPlayer uses the system volume (controlled by the hardware volume switch) for media playback.

Use the **MPVolumeView** class to present the user with a slider control in your application for setting the system audio output volume

See the [MPVolumeView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

You can mute the playback of audio with AVPlayer by creating an AVAudioMix with a volume ramp to set the volume to 0 as shown below

**Muting the playback of audio with AVPlayer by creating an AVAudioMix with zero volume ramp.**

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self myAssetURL] options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

// Mute all the audio tracks
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

// Create a player item
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix]; // Mute the player item

// Create a new Player, and set the player to use the player item 
// with the muted audio mix
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

// assign player object to an instance variable
self.mPlayer = player;

// play the muted audio
[mPlayer play];
```

Comment: AVPlayer didn't have volume property. It's not AVAudioPlayer. and my audio file's volume is not low, it's only appear in my app.

Comment: thank you. i found the problem.It is AVAudioSession, if i remove all code about my AVAudioSession setting, volume become normal.But i still don't know how to set AVAudioSession.

Comment: and i found answer here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246374/low-recording-volume-in-combination-with-avaudiosessioncategoryplayandrecord