# I can Only Hear Recorder Audio When Headphone are Plugged

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

So I am trying to recorder and audio the play it back when I do that using simulator it work as expected , but on a my phone or any phone I can only hear it using headphones? this is my recording and playing functions 
Update : I have noticed  that the recodering is not working as well on my phone :Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker"

```
  func startRecording() {
        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]

        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }



  func playAudio(fileData:Data){
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData)
            if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
                audioPlayer.delegate  = self
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.volume = 2.0
                audioPlayer.play()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: volume 2.0? seems quite low

Comment: Actually the maximum is 1. But this is also the default so I don’t see the point of setting it at all.

Comment: What are your AVAudioSession category settings?

Comment: I dont not set  AVAudioSession category

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246374/low-recording-volume-in-combination-with-avaudiosessioncategoryplayandrecord/

Comment: is there are swift Ver cuz I am familiar  with object C